# checkbox defalut checked and also disabled in React.js not working

Tags: sass, hover, checked, disabled-input, bem

Hi im trying to make a switch button (checkbox) with default checked and also disabled in react. 
but somehow if I only put checked={true} it will be checked but the moment i add disabled="disabled", the switch button is unchecked and disabled (even if there is checked attribute). Could anyone please advise? thank you

```
 <label htmlFor="disabled-on" className="switch__label">
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="disabled-on"
                id="disabled-on"
                checked={true}
                disabled="disabled"  /* if added disabled it's not working with checked" */
                className="switch__input switch__input--disabled-on"
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably something wrong in your code somewhere else, please check this code - all looks fine.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
          <label htmlFor="disabled-on" className="switch__label">
             custom checkbox 1
              <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="disabled-on"
                  id="disabled-on"
                  checked={true}
                  disabled="disabled"
                  className="switch__input switch__input--disabled-on"
              />
          </label>
          </li><li>
          <label htmlFor="disabled-on" className="switch__label">
             custom checkbox 2
              <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="disabled-off"
                  id="disabled-off"
                  checked={true}
                  className="switch__input switch__input--disabled-on"
              />
          </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi  Thank you very much. I will check my Sass then. :)

Comment: Thank you for the tips, found out now why...it's the css definition in my Sass that did not define the checked style :) thanks alot ~